# system policy prevents unlocking or controlling the mobile broadband device?

Tags: system, 15.04, usb-modem, modem-manager, policy

Keep getting this pop-up requiring me to enter my password when I have Modem Manager GUI open. It happens every 5 mins, as long as Modem Manager is open.

How do i change my system policy to allow the manager.?

Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 3):

The message is defined and raised by [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/) in the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.policy`.

Ideal is for the author of Modem Manager GUI to define a polkit policy (see the "Declaring Actions" section in the [polkit documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html)) that would be shipped in future versions of the application.

Meanwhile, you can add a set of authorization rules in `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` in a file named something like `30-modem-manager-gui.rules` as per the "Authorization Rules" section in the polkit docs I referenced above.

An example rule that checks for the specific message you get and that won't show the message if you are a `sudo` user:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Device.Control" &&
        subject.local && subject.active && 
        (subject.isInGroup ("sudo"))) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});
```

Other users, please help improve this answer with a better example. This is my first stack exchange answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a direct alternative to Njenga's answer, you can edit file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.policy` directly. Search for the block that governs the action id "org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Device.Control":

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Device.Control">                                                                                                                                                  
  <description>Unlock and control a mobile broadband device</description>
  <message>System policy prevents unlocking or controlling the mobile broadband device.</message>
  [... other languages skipped...]
  <defaults>                                                                                                                                    
    <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>auth_self_keep</allow_active>
  </defaults>
</action>
```

In the line starting with `<allow_active>`, replace `auth_self_keep` with `yes`. After a reboot, Modem started working without any prompt for me (16.04).